# Partitioning scheme for a virtual machine host

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, kvm

I am planning to use an Ubuntu Server 12.04 with KVM to create 2 virtual machines.
Reading some docs on the net, I have found that a good approach is to use LVM based VM, so my idea is to have:

- 1 ext2 partition for boot
- 1 LVG with 3 logical volumes: 1 for host, 1 for vm1 and 1 for vm2

Is this a good partitioning scheme? What factors do I need to consider?

Comment: As grub2 supports LVM just use one LV and no dedicated /boot partition.

Comment: Isn't this a little subjective for the Q&A format?

Comment: ext2? Is that still supported by Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

My typical setup looks something like:

1. Software raid over the block devices (either Level 1 or 5)
2. One Physical Volume & Volume Group over Software raid
3. One LV for `/` as grub nowadays can cope with LVM and raid without a problem. There is in my opinion no need for a dedicated boot partition
4. Depending on your system either a extra LV for `/var/log` or `/home`

So yes your scheme should work. If you have multiple disks you can also consider using dedicated disks for your virtual machines and use different ones for your operating system. It really depends on your hardware and your requirements.

As you are using `kvm` make sure to use `virtio` and [disable caching](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Tuning_KVM) for your block device.

In general you should identify your requirements, e.g. fast, reliable, secure (e.g. no user should be able to cause an disk space full for system daemons) etc. and design your system around it.